# Why is my cooker tripping circuit breakers?

Tags: electrical

I have a four burner stove with an oven. I would like to know why it keeps tripping the power when in use.
It has a six position cam switch, and two of the four plates trip the circuit breaker at all positions 1 to 6. The remaining two start tripping at position 4 up to 6.

I have not tried resetting the breakers everytime the they trip.

Comment: If you have not reset the circuit breaker how can you use it again? Did you mean to say you have reset the breaker each time it trips? What size circuit breaker is your stove connected to? The minimum size circuit for a range is 40 amps. This is normally plenty for a standard range.

Comment: What make and model is this stove?

Comment: What kind of breaker do you have on the circuit for this range? Our tract house (built1970) has a standard 50-A double pole breaker for the range circuit. The originally installed range was a single unit builder's grade Gaffer and Sattler unit with two ovens and an integral evacuation hood. About 30 years ago I replaced it with a moderate price GE slide in with one oven. I put in a Vent-a-Hood powered by an available wire to a 120 V circuit, i.e., the vent fan and light is not powered by the 240-V circuit for the range. The GE instructions say to use a 40-A breaker, but I just left the 50-A.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the timing of your post, English style, and the way you describe your circuit breakers and outage... I am guessing you are in the UK.  You did not mention any blinding, destructive explosion of arc and fire, which says this is not a "dead short" type overcurrent trip.

That all correlates. It's quite common in the UK to have the entire house protected by a RCD, or Residual Current (ground fault) Detector. **Your stove has a *ground fault*.**

It's possible it has a single ground fault somewhere in the stove's wiring, possibly in the return (neutral) wiring.

It's also possible it has four separate ground faults, one in each burner, owing to a pattern of use, cleaning or maintenance.

Or there may be a fault in the building wiring.

Comment: If the entire house is protected by a single RCD, then a ground fault in any appliance would cut off power to the entire house!  Can it really be this way?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that two of the plates cause the breaker to trip even on the lowest setting suggests a problem with the range itself rather than the power supply.

Is the range in good condition?  Is it clean - especially under the burner area (if that area is accessible)?

I say the above because at the lowest settings the range should draw the least amount of power and not trip the breaker at all, and for that matter if the house is properly wired the range should not trip the breaker even if all burners and the oven are on high.

If there is damage somewhere inside the range - or even a build up of conductive contaminants (grease, water, etc) then there may be some kind of electrical short occurring that only can occur when power is supplied.  It would be unusual but I can't think of any reason why a breaker would trip at the lowest settings otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Breaker (over current protection), GFCI's, AFCI's are all protection devices that kill the circuit before causing a possible burn or shock hazard. So if you stove or range is tripping a breaker (I am assuming a 50 amp 2 pole breaker). Then something is very wrong with your range. Since you have tried to reset the breaker and it continued to trip. You need to turn the breaker off and either have the range repaired and tested or buy a new one.

Electrical faults do not repair themselves. Attempting to reset a breaker and continued tripping will cause further damage to your circuit and breaker. So you might want to contact a local service electrician to check out your circuit also.

I need to warn you that this is a potentially dangerous situation so do not try to reset the breaker and use the range until repairs are made.